# Intermittent Android app crash java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

Our app is currently running in TC56 and TC57 devices, and we are observing intermittent crashes in few devices.

```
[Events]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.XXX.XXX-9biWE6eu2GZJuAqHQGqPpw==/lib/arm/libcrashmanager-ndk.so" has bad ELF magic
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
at com.XXX.device.crashmanager.ndk.NDKCrashDetector.<init>(NDKCrashDetector.java:3)
at com.XXX.device.crashmanager.CrashDetectionHelper.enableNDKCrashDetection(CrashDetectionHelper.java:1)
at com.XXX.XXX.android.log.CustomCrashReporterImpl.initialise(CustomCrashReporterImpl.java:6)
at com.XXX.XXX.android.XXX.onCreate(XXX.java:5)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5765)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1669)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6528)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

We came across this which is very similar to our crashes. I have validated we are using
`osVersion: 8.1.0` which is greater than what is suggested in answer.

One of the main reason is this is intermittent failure

Answer (score 1):

You're using a library libcrashmanager-ndk that is corrupted in some way.  "Bad ELF magic" means that the first 4 bytes (I think 4, may be off on size) of the file are not the magic combo expected to recognize an ELF file.  ELF files are linux executable files.  The only fix for this is to get a good version of the library (or not to use it at all).

Comment: The problem with library will result in app crash every time?...or it can cause intermittent crash as well?....

Comment: Every time it tries to load the library.  If it doesn't need to load the library, it wouldn't crash.  It could also be a problem if you're running on an ABI incompatible device.  The play store shouldn't allow you to be downloaded, but if you're sideloading that can happen.